# When and how to use 家は, 家から, ここは, and ここから

Tags: grammar, word-order

What is the difference of the following:

a) 家はここから近いです
b) ここは家から近いです
c) ここから家は近いです
d) 家からここは近いです

Edit:
This is what I think of the Japanese above: a) my house is near here, b) this place is near my house, c) from here my house is near, and d) from my house this place is near. I am not sure if I am correct and I don’t know when to use these sentences.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to the Japanese stack exchange. We typically require some information about where you've looked for information or what you think the Japanese in question might mean before answering questions like this, so updating your post with some of that information would help it get answered more quickly.

Comment: @Mindful Thank you for your fast response. This is what I think of the Japanese above: a) my house is near here, b) this place is near my house, c) from here my house is near, and d) from my house this place is near. I am not sure if I am correct and I don’t know when to use these sentences.

Comment: from my understanding, A & C and B & D would mean the same, as the only part that matters as per Japanese sentence order is that the verb comes at the end (please check  [this](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/debunking-the-japanese-sentence-order-myth/)).